# last-of-type selector not working as expected

Tags: html, css

I would like to use the selector last-of-type to target only the last input in every form in my application.

That's the html:

```css
.form-input:last-of-type {
          margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
```

```html
      <form role="form"
          method="POST"
          action="{{ route('login') }}">
          {{ csrf_field() }}
          <div class="form-input">
              <label>Username</label>
              <input id="email"
                  placeholder="Enter your email"
                  type="email"
                  name="email"
                  value="{{ old('email') }}"
                  required autofocus>
          </div>
          <div class="form-input"> <!-- That's the element I want to target-->
              <label>Password</label>
              <!-- or this one -->
              <input id="password"                   
                  placeholder="Enter your password"
                  type="password"
                  name="password"
                  required>                          
          </div>

          <div class="buttonWrapper">
              <button type="submit">Login</button>
          </div>
          <div style="padding-bottom: 20px;" class="text--center">
              <a class="text--uppercase text--condensed" href="">
                  Forgot Your Password?
              </a>
          </div>
      </form>
```

Basically I want the last .form-input class to have more padding-bottom or the input of the last .form-input to have more margin-bottom (the effect is the same).

I was trying to use something like this:

That code target also the first input, adding a margin between every input.

I have also tried :last-child but doesn't work if there are more nodes under the one that I want to target.

There's a way around this?

Comment: I want to target every last input tag in every form tag. Should I add dashes somewhere?

Comment: Last of type only applies to the direct parent, so you can't target the last input element of the form if there is a wrapper div around that input (it will instead look for the last input of that wrapper).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `<div>`s and `<label>`s use `<fieldset>`s and `<legend>`s because:

- It makes your `<form>` semantically perfect.
- It looks better
- Using CSS as the main means of finding elements in the DOM is very limiting, so having `<div>`s and `<span>`s everywhere will lessen your chances at getting specific selectors.

Now your layout is semantic, and using `nth-of-type` is a no brainer:

## Demo

```css
fieldset:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  border-color: red
}
```

```html
<form role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <fieldset class="form-input">
    <legend>Username</legend>
    <input id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="form-input">
    <legend>Password</legend>
    <input id="password" placeholder="Enter your password" type="password" name="password" required>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="form-input">
    <legend>Username</legend>
    <input id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="form-input">
    <legend>Password</legend>
    <input id="password" placeholder="Enter your password" type="password" name="password" required>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="form-input">
    <legend>Username</legend>
    <input id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="form-input">
    <legend>Password</legend>
    <input id="password" placeholder="Enter your password" type="password" name="password" required>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="form-input">
    <legend>Username</legend>
    <input id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="form-input">
    <legend>Password</legend>
    <input id="password" placeholder="Enter your password" type="password" name="password" required>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="form-input">
    <legend>Username</legend>
    <input id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="form-input">
    <legend>Password</legend>
    <input id="password" placeholder="Enter your password" type="password" name="password" required>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="form-input">
    <legend>Username</legend>
    <input id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="form-input">
    <legend>Password</legend>
    <input id="password" placeholder="Enter your password" type="password" name="password" required>
  </fieldset>

  <div class="buttonWrapper">
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
  </div>
  <div style="padding-bottom: 20px;" class="text-center">
    <a class="text-uppercase text-condensed" href="">
              Forgot Your Password?
          </a>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment above, last of type only applies to the direct parent, so you can't target the last input element of the form if there is a wrapper div around that input (it will instead look for the last input of that wrapper). You also unfortunately can't pass it a class to target the last ".form-input".

The only way I can see to do this without using something unreliable like nth-child (and short of editing your HTML to add an extra class or something) is with JavaScript. Fortunately it's pretty simple to get the last .form-input and add a ".last" class, if you're not averse to doing it this way:

```
document.querySelectorAll('form').forEach(function(el) {
   el.querySelectorAll('.form-input')[el.querySelectorAll('.form-input').length-1].classList.add('last2');
});
```

Edit: updated to handle all forms.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't use `last-of-type` on scenarios like this. You could achieve the same result by wrapping all your `form-input` together like this:

```
<div class="form-input-container"> <!-- Apply margin here-->
    <div class="form-input">...</div>
    <div class="form-input">...</div>
    ....
</div>
<div class="buttonWrapper">
```

Answer (score 0):

The `:last-of-type` pseudo-class means "last element *of its type* (i.e. with this tag name) in the container". In your markup, the element you want to select is not the last `div` in the container, so it doesn't match the selector.

In CSS Selectors level 3, there is no way to select "the last element with the certain class". There is such a possibility in the CSS Selectors level 4 (in your case, it would be `:nth-last-child(1 of .form-input)`), but it's supported only in Safari.

To solve your problem, there are the following ways:

1. Use different tags for `.form-input` wrappers and other wrappers, so
   you could use `:last-of-type` to select the last of them (as
   **zer00ne** suggests);
2. Assuming that `.form-input` wrappers always come before other things in the form, you can add the top margin to the next element after the last `.form-input`, instead of the bottom margin to the `.form-input`, with the selector like the following: `.form-input + :not(.form-input) { margin-top: 10px; }`